# I am trying to replaceEvens with a "0" in java, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static int[] replaceEvens(int[] a)  {
    int e[] = new int[a.length];
    // TODO Insert code here
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if( e[0]%2 == 0){
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    return e;
}
```

I believe this code is right but I am getting 0's for all numbers in the Array
the Array is { 5,  15, 24, 35, 2, 7, 8}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several problems;

- e[] is not having any values populated in it, it is just being initialised with the length of a
- you are setting i to equal zero in your if statement, you probably mean to set e[i] = 0
- you are only comparing e[0] %2 == 0, you probably mean to compare e[i] % 2 ==0

putting it all together the for loop you intended to write was probably:

```
int e[] = a.clone();

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if( e[i]%2 == 0){
        e[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the fact that he created a new array and that he has `int[]` as return value for the method, I suspect he doesn't want to modify the original array.

Comment: Good point, updated my answer, though your solution is better

Comment: the solution from @aioobe is definitely better; I'd use that rather than mine

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code isn't correct.
First of all, it is quite surprising you don't get an infinite loop. It is not done to mess with the loop-variable in a for-loop. If you would want to do that, use a while-loop.
Second point is that your if-statement contains e, which is up to that point not initialised, and thus only contains variables = 0.
Third point: you always check for the same value e[0], so you only check the first value of array e in every iteration

I hope this helps you enough to correct the code by yourself now...
(otherwise see the answer from beresfordt)